# How to echo MySQL database has not returned anything?

Tags: php, html, mysql

My problem is that if a user types in a value that is not in my database the page stays blank. I wish to display a message saying their postcode is not valid. I have had a look through other posts and can't seem to get it to work with my code.

The user searches in a text box to find out the 'price' of delivery for their postcode i.e. they search m6 and it returns m6 - 0.50 in a table. If say they typed sk1, which is not part of the delivery area I want to display a message

What I have done is as follows:

index.php

```
<section id="post">
<p id="post"> postage calculator for manchester: </P>

    <?PHP
session_start();
     echo 'total cost £'. $_SESSION['postage'];
              ?>

    <form action="shop.php" method="post">
    <input class="text" type="text" name="postsub" min="0">
    <input class="button" type="submit" name="postsub1" value="postsub" >
    </form>
    </section>
```

process.php:

```
function button6() {

 $search_value = $_POST["postsub"];
 $codequery = "SELECT * FROM postage WHERE postcode LIKE '%$search_value%'";

 // connect to database
     $dbh= new PDO('mysql:host='.$hostname.';dbname='.$dbname,$username,$password);

  //generate SQL query
 $result=$dbh->prepare($codequery);

 //execute query
 $result->execute();

// display result
echo '<table id="tab">';
while($row=$result->fetch()){
echo '<tr>';
echo '<td>'.$row['postcode'].'</td>';
echo '<td>'.$row['price'].'</td>';
echo '</tr>';

 if (mysqli_num_rows($result)==0) { echo "no result"; }

  }
  echo '</table>';
 }
```

This is how it returns on a positive search and I just want the postode and price, and then when it is not any of those just display no result:

```
no resultno resultno resultno resultno resultno resultno result
m1  0.50
m2  0.50
m3  0.70
m4  0.70
m5  1
m6  1
m7  1.20
```

Comment: Unrelated to current question but current prepared statement is being used incorrectly. Need to parameterize.

Comment: What is `mysqli_num_rows`? Remove that.

Comment: `session_start();` after output also won't work, that needs to be one of your first lines.

Comment: @Dharman I just saw it in another post with a related issue as an answer. At this time I am only learning the basics, I'm not focusing on security just to get it to work

Comment: You can't mix `PDO` and `mysqli` functions. You also wouldn't want that in the `while` if there are no results you wont enter `while`.

Answer (score -2):

Your function has plenty of problems. A simple fix would be to remove the invalid `mysqli_num_rows()` and the `if` statement and parameterize the SQL. You should also connect once outside the function and then pass the connection into the function.

The best choice usually is to fetch all rows into an array and then have an `if` statement based on that data. If you have no values in `$data` then display some message.

```
function button6(PDO $dbh) {
    $search_value = $_POST["postsub"];
    $codequery = "SELECT * FROM postage WHERE postcode LIKE ?";
   
    //generate SQL query
    $result = $dbh->prepare($codequery);
   
    //execute query
    $result->execute(["%$search_value%"]);
    $data = $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
   
    if ($data) {
        // display result
        echo '<table id="tab">';
        foreach ($data as $row) {
            echo '<tr>';
            echo '<td>'.$row['postcode'].'</td>';
            echo '<td>'.$row['price'].'</td>';
            echo '</tr>';
        }
        echo '</table>';
    } else {
        echo 'No results!';
    }
}
```

To connect with PDO simply have this piece of code in a single place in your application.

```
$pdo = new \PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=$dbname;charset=utf8mb4", $username,$password, [
    \PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    \PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false
]);
```

Then when you call the function simply pass it as an argument.

```
button6($pdo);
```

Comment: when you say connect outside and pass the connection. How would this be implemented? @dharman

Comment: @HarryKnott I added more explanation

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
<?php
function button6() {

$search_value = $_POST["postsub"];
$codequery = "SELECT * FROM postage WHERE postcode LIKE '%$search_value%'";

// connect to database
    $dbh= new PDO('mysql:host='.$hostname.';dbname='.$dbname,$username,$password);

 //generate SQL query
$result=$dbh->prepare($codequery);

//execute query
$result->execute();

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td>'.$row['postcode'].'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$row['price'].'</td>';
        echo '</tr>';    
    }
} else {
    echo "No results";
}  

} 

?>
```

Comment: When I have tried to implement this every result returns as ' no results '

Comment: What is this? Please add some explanation.